# Credentials for an AWS Lambda function using S3 event source and SES send_mail

Tags: amazon-s3, smtp, aws-lambda, credentials, amazon-ses

---

I am confused about how to set up permissions for Lambda function to (1) process event from S3 and then (2) send an e-mail using SES.

I have 3 IAM users set up -- account owner (me), and "adminuser" with all my admin rights, and an ses-smtp-user user with the "special" SMTP ID and secret key needed apparently for SES.

How can I give Lambda all the permission it needs to access both services?

Without hard-coding the keys in the function, of course!!!

===
Update: I was able to run Lambda function successfully using the "adminuser" credentials WITHOUT making any reference to or use of the special "SMTP" credentials that the SES documentation seems to suggest are required. Maybe they are not needed for Lambda functions?  Maybe they are no longer needed at all?

Comment: Please re-read your question, and ask yourself, "if someone else had my problem in the future, would they be able to realize that fact from reading this?"  Please focus on one issue at a time.

Comment: OK, hope this edited version is better--thanks.